# How to change icon in result message ant-design library?

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript, ant-design-pro

I am preparing result messages for app (React + Ant-desing + TypeScript). There I should change icons from default icons (from ant-design to custom according my design file).

[Screen with custom icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAFAE.jpg)

Accordingly to docs of 'ant design' there is a way to put custom icon.
[https://ant.design/components/result/#components-result-demo-customIcon%5C]
I used it.

But result with status 403,404,500 have another logic for building this result message. They has additional class name for icon wrapper and I can't rewrite icon from ant design to my own icon.

It looks like that
[Screen with default icon that should be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyp4S.jpg)

If anybody has an idea what to do with that?

My code for result you can see here

```
<Result
    status='403'
    icon={<Lock />}
    title='403'
    subTitle='Sorry, you are not authorized to access this page.'
    extra={
        <Button
            type='primary'
            className='submit_btn flex_center'
        >
            <ArrowCircleLeft />
            Back
        </Button>
    }
/>

<Result
    status='404'
    icon={<CloseCircle />}
    title='404'
    subTitle='Sorry, the page you visited does not exist.'
    extra={
        <Button
            type='primary'
            className='submit_btn flex_center'
        >
            <ArrowCircleLeft />
            Back
        </Button>
    }
/>
```

But line with property "icon" don't work (still stay icon by default from ant-design)

Comment: Did you create this custom icon named `<Lock />` or is from another library?

Comment: I've just tried  with a custom icon and it worked fine, make sure you are importing correctly the icon. https://codesandbox.io/s/info-antd-4-24-2-forked-5kst6q?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: Hello have you tried to remove status ? Documentation said that `Result status, decide icons and colors `

Comment: @S.Marx i have problems only with status 403,404,500. With my icons there are no problems. This problem appear only when i set status for result 403,404,500 (with another statuses there are no problem)

Comment: @LansanaDiomande when I remove status problem disappear. But I should leave this status for logic.